# how can change vuejs 2 router query + laravel 5.2

Tags: javascript, php, vuejs2

first sry for my bad english. (i'm newbie :D)
i has issue when i use vue to get ajax data and change some filters like page. sort and... in my url query (params) and send it to server and get new data. and also update url for if user copy the url and paste it for example in another browser show same data.
so i use this way after many many search in net.
i want to know my solution is ok (and standard?) ? or this is bad idea?
my view:

```
<div id="app" class="row" v-cloak>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="filters">
                <div class="categories">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="filter-category" v-for="category in categories" v-on:click="changeFilterByCat(category.id)">
                            <router-link :to="{ name: 'filter', query: { query }}">@{{ category.title }}</router-link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="teachers">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="filter-teacher" v-for="teacher in teachers" v-on:click="changeFilterByTeacher(teacher.id)">
                            <router-link :to="{ name: 'filter', query: { query }}">@{{ teacher.name }}</router-link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and my vue js codes:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        { path: "/", name: 'filter'}
    ]
});

var app = new Vue({
    router,
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        baseUrl: '{{ route("MY-URL",cat-name)}}',
        products: '',
        categories: '',
        teachers: '',
        query: {
            page: 1,
            take: 2,
            ct: '',
            tcr: '',
            srt: 'adc'
        }
    },
    mounted: function () {
        this.setUrlParams();
        this.getData();
    },
    methods: {
        setUrlParams(){
            if(this.$route.query.page){
                this.query = this.$route.query;
            }
            router.push({ name: 'filter', query: this.query});
        },
        getData(){
            console.log(this.baseUrl+this.$route.fullPath);
            this.$http.get(this.baseUrl+this.$route.fullPath)
                .then(function (response) {
                    this.products = response.body.products;
                    this.categories = response.body.categories;
                    this.teachers = response.body.teachers;
                });
        },
        changeFilterByCat(catID){
            this.query.ct = catID;
            router.push({ name: 'filter', query: this.query});
        },
        changeFilterByTeacher(teacherId){
            this.query.tcr = teacherId;
            router.push({ name: 'filter', query: this.query});
        }
    }
});
```